# Is it importent to publish update of an app to see adds using admob?

Tags: firebase, flutter, admob, firebase-admob

I have build an app using flutter and its already available on play store. I want to intigrate that app with admob for which i am using `admob_flutter:`.

Test ad is working on app but when using my BannerId its giving `error code 3`. My account has been aproved by admodmob and its been 3 days.

In payments method its not showing how you get paid, and i guess its because you have to reach threshold atleast once but i have added other details. Intigeration with firebase is also working fine. So do i need to publish the update to get my first ad on my app, or is there something that i am doing wrong.

Comment: Take a look at admob error codes - https://support.google.com/admob/thread/3494603/admob-error-codes-logs?hl=en . Also make sure on your apps.admob.com -> App -> App Settings. App is linked to live app

Answer (score 1):

No, for example I put the app in the store, it took a few days to display the real ad.
Test ads are normally displayed in debug mode, check that the Test ads in debugging is really working.
However, as ads took a while after sending to the playstore. good luck with your project.